# Google Charts: Adding a margin to the hAxis labels

Tags: canvas, svg, charts, google-visualization

So I'd like to add some extra spacing between the x axis labels and the graph.

I've tried using the hAxis.textStyle and setting marginTop to a value, but it's not working.

Has anyone had luck doing this?